# Can we create layers in Google datastudio Bubble map to plot and compare data ; similar to Google Mymaps

Tags: geospatial, looker-studio, mymaps

I have a table showing order projection on pincode level

How I'm creating Chart

1. Create a Datastudio - Datasource and add the relevant gsheet containing data below:
2. Edit pincode as Postal code
3. Create a report > Create a Bubble Map and plot pincodes with projected load.
   [Output Data Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRieu.jpg)

Sample Chart for Projected Load
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/74fcbbe7-de10-4162-ac5d-6e3fc3a23339

Chart 2 for Current Capacity - Showing capacity in Green Color
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/93053f41-832a-4870-a823-cd010d97c469

Expected Output - Merge two Charts into One chart showing Postal code wise Projected and Current Capacity.

I want to add the current capacity in a different color to decide on building new capacity. #Logistics
Can this be done using data studio?? or pl suggest a different tool.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3OPettlFWYiNuIBG3SWKC007iYTAQmHwXzV2E87RgQ/edit#gid=0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nZY3pQ0Nz_QyQe7FWs5L-fk3X6q1x07umUKv51afq8/edit#gid=0

| pincode | city | Country | Orders Projection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110081 | Delhi | India | 1962 |
| 110032 | Delhi | India | 1696 |
| 110043 | Delhi | India | 1386 |
| 110093 | Delhi | India | 828 |
| 110083 | Delhi | India | 816 |
| 110077 | Delhi | India | 579 |
| 110091 | Delhi | India | 537 |
| 110087 | Delhi | India | 412 |
| 110095 | Delhi | India | 345 |

Table 2 - Existing Capacity

| pincode | city | Country | Current Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110032 | Delhi | India | 250 |
| 201301 | Noida | India | 300 |